# Need explanation of time complexity solution of algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

My intro to software engineering class has just hit time complexity and learning how to analyze certain algorithms. I'm having difficulty seeing how they got to their solution and was hoping someone could explain it, hopefully with some logical proof?

```
void foo(int N) {
    int k = 1;
    while (k < N * N) {
        k = k * 2;
    }
}
```

Their solution is that Big-O of this function is **O(logN)** [I understand that log here is base 2]

I tried to solve this by thinking how many times it would iterate by assigning random values to N and I couldn't find a pattern, any help?

Comment: Write out the values of `k` and `N` in binary. It should all make sense then

Comment: Use a maths program/library to plot the number of loops versus increasing values of N.

Comment: @user6918211: if you feel that one of the answers below is sufficient, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `k` is being increased by a factor of `2` each time is what makes the algorithm `logN`. Actually, it's `log(N^2)`, but using the properties of logarithms we can simplify it to `2log(N)` and then drop the `2` by taking the limit as `N` approaches infinity to get `log(N)`.

Thus, the time complexity is `O(logN)`.

EDIT: Additionally, it can be seen that `k` starts at `1` and the program ends when `k` is greater than or equal to `N * N`. If we take the `log(N^2)`, we will know how many iterations through which the program will run. In doing so, we will also be able to determine the ending value of `k` by taking the ceiling of `log(N^2)`.

EDIT: An example would be `N = 10`: The square of `N` is `100`. Thus, `k` will increase until the power of two above or equal to `100`, which is `128`.

Answer (score 2):

Use your high school algebra.  After `p` iterations the value of `k` is `2^p`.  (It's easy to check this.)  The loop will stop executing when `k >= N^2`.  Substituting, the loop stops when

```
2^p >= N^2
```

Now solve:

```
log_2(2^p) >= log(N^2)
p >= 2 log(N)
```

So the loop will stop at very close to `2 log(N)` iterations. This is O(log(N)).

You might take your teacher to task by pointing out that multiplication is constant time only if there's a fixed limit on the size of operands. With no such limit, the problem depends on the asymptotic behavior of multiplication as well.

Incidentally, O(log N) is the same for all bases of the logarithm. The base changes the value of the log only by a constant factor, and big-O ignores constant factors.